# What is the correct approach to creating library of similar parts?

Tags: altium

When coming to components like LEDs, resistors, capacitors e.t.c there are throngs of manufacturers and suppliers that provide parts that are very similar from PCB design perspective i.e the schematic symbol and footprint. What approach then does one take when designing parts libraries?

Lets take an example, lets say I have a 0805 SMD resistor. Its schematic symbol will be the same regardless of the actual resistor resistance value. There are throngs of manufacturers that manufacture this type of resistor and the physical dimensions of the part and the pad to solder it onto, are going to be almost identical or be so similar that a single footprint can be used for all the parts regardless of who manufactures it.

Now from library design perspective, do we create a different schematic symbol for each manufacturer part number which can change based on the value of resistance and then also create a whole lot of foot prints to match the dimensions of every single manufacturer, or take a simpler approach? If so, what is the simpler approach going to  be?

Here are some LEDs that I need to put into my Altium library for the project. They are all in 1206 package. How do I go about creating the library for these?

inolux

1. [LED AMBER CLEAR 1206 SMD (IN-S126ATA)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/inolux/IN-S126ATA/7604903)
2. [LED GREEN CLEAR 1206 SMD (IN-S126ATG)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/inolux/IN-S126ATG/7604905)
3. [LED RED CLEAR 1206 SMD (IN-S126ATR)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/inolux/IN-S126ATR/7604906)

visual-communications-company-vcc

1. [LED GREEN DIFFUSED 1206 SMD (CMD15-21VGD-TR8)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/visual-communications-company-vcc/CMD15-21VGD-TR8/254844)
2. [LED RED CLEAR 1206 SMD (CMD11-21VRC-TR8)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/visual-communications-company-vcc/CMD11-21VRC-TR8/254829)
3. [LED YELLOW DIFFUSED 1206 SMD (CMD15-21VYD-TR8)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/visual-communications-company-vcc/CMD15-21VYD-TR8/254845)

lumex-opto-components-inc

1. [LED RED CLEAR 1206 SMD (SML-LX1206SIC-TR)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/lumex-opto-components-inc/SML-LX1206SIC-TR/467543)
2. [LED GREEN CLEAR 1206 SMD (SML-LX1206GC-TR)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/lumex-opto-components-inc/SML-LX1206GC-TR/229139) ([specs](https://www.lumex.com/spec/SML-LX1206SIC-TR.pdf))

bivar-inc

1. [LED YELLOW CLEAR 1206 SMD (SM1206NYC-IL)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/bivar-inc/SM1206NYC-IL/5030135)
2. [LED GREEN CLEAR 1206 SMD (SM1206GC-IL)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/products/detail/bivar-inc/SM1206GC-IL/3095544)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question comes down to personal preference, so I am not sure how good of a question it is for this board. That being said, I am aware of at least a few approaches in industry.

At some companies the libraries are completely generic and the library only contains components such as "RESISTOR 0402". It is then up to the designer to populate the parameter fields with information such as value, tolerance, part number, etc. One potential issue here is that the designer has to spend time finding an appropriate part number and populating the parameters.

Alternatively, some companies have library components for specific combinations of parameters, but still do not specify the final part number. For example "RESISTOR 0402 4.7k 1% 1/4 W". There are, of course, many part numbers that satisfy those parameters but there is enough detail to defer the effort of actually selecting the final part number to another team. In this case, the designer has to do less work.

Finally, I have also seen discrete parts for every unique part number. This has the most up-front cost but requires no additional effort once the parts have been entered into the library.

For hobbyists or individual users, I would recommend one of the first two solutions. You will save a lot of time entering new components that you will likely never use again.

EDIT: Just saw the edit to the original question. Of course, this is only a suggestion, but if I were you I would probably separate the library components by landing pattern and color, but not necessarily by part number or manufacturer. For example, I would probably make:

LED SMD 1206 RED

LED SMD 1206 YELLOW

LED SMD 1206 GREEN

etc...

You can optionally also add components to differentiate between clear/diffused

Comment: The first question that arises is, how will BOM be created without specific part numbers be selected?

Comment: Also, I assume that copy paste approach would be use to create a large number of identical schematic symbols or PCB foot prints. Now if there was a need to make changes to remove error or otherwise, the library maintainers will have to go through every single schematic symbol and library footprint to make that change. That looks like a lot of wasted time and effort.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 The difference between the approaches is *when you decide the part numbers. If you are working individually and do not have a team that assigns real part numbers to generic ones, your options are to either enter the part numbers when you make thy symbol (option #3) or when you place the component on the schematic (option #1/2).

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 You are correct, the nice thing about having individual components for each part number is that you can perform global updates from the libraries in the case you need to change something. But you should also consider the cost of making a new entry in the library for every new part number. Once again, there are pros and cons to all approaches.

Comment: I had thought that the EDA industry would have completely sorted this out by now but it seems this is not exactly the case since the most robust approach has not been found yet. Each approach seems to be having disadvantages.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 It's not really the "industry's" problem since the optimal solution depends on the environment the software is being used in. For large engineering companies, having generic part numbers and a separate team to assign the final part numbers and keep track of product stock is optimal because it speeds up the design time (since engineering does not need to worry about assigning part numbers or swapping part numbers when stock runs out). There is no such clear optimal solution for individuals.

Comment: What is meant by "global updates"?

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 When you update your schematic symbols from the libraries and it automatically applies any changes you made to the library components across all of your schematics (so you avoid having to manually update every instance of a part when you want to make a change)

Comment: Yes correct, but what if I have 100 identical schematic symbols of LED and then I need to make a change that shall apply to all of them. I am talking about library management here actually.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 if you have 100 identical instances of a single library symbol, and then change the definition of that symbol in the library, you can click one button (in Altium, for example) and it will go through all the symbols in your schematic and update to the latest versions from the library, updating all 100 instances at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to settle out: LEDs are *not* generic. There are differences, even within the same color, that could cause you to have LEDs that are not bright enough or too bright, have the wrong forward voltage, or the wrong shade (like the difference between ‘green’ and ‘true green’ for example.)

You need to assign an Approved Vendor List (AVL) to LEDs.

Resistors and capacitors, although you’d think they’d be generic, again often they’re not: they have a lot of parameters like formulation, tolerance, voltage, thermal rating and so forth. Need an AVL for those too.

So when you create a part, it should have at least three things:

- A unique, self-created part number. You index this from your schematic to create a BOM
- A description
- An AVL list of manufacturer part numbers

Anything that’s not on the AVL needs to be reviewed, approved and added by someone knowledgeable.

Comment: I agree that this is a valid and good approach. It is not the only approach. I have been at multiple companies that do not do it this way. A common hybrid approach I have seen is to have both generics and unique pns in the library. Where something generic will suffice, you can use that. Where specific requirements must be met, you use the symbol with the unique pn linked. The supply chain team then fills in the pns for the generics before assembly.